# PHP Conditional Question

Tags: php, include, conditional-statements

Hello StackOverflow Community, I hope you guys can help me with this here:

On my homepage I have a DIV structure that basically have a `<div id="container">` that has an `<h1>` and a `<div id="content">`.

I also have some JavaScript that makes the `<div id="content">` slide up/down when the `<h1>` is clicked, by inserting or removing a class ".open" to the `<div id="content">`.

Now I want to create using PHP and conditional that echo something if the  `<div id="content">` has the class  ".open" and something else if not.

This is what i was trying to do:

There is a Javascript like this:

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(function() {
                        $('.container h1').bind('click', function() {
                            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
                                $(this).parent().find('.content').slideUp();
                                $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                                return 0;
                            }
                            $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideUp();
                            $(this).parent().find('.content').slideDown();
                            $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                        })
                     });
            </script>
```

That works on this:

```
            <div id="container">
                <h1><a href="javascript:void(null)">Open the content</a></h1>
                <div id="content">
                    <p>Content 1</p>
                </div>  
            </div>      
            <div id="container">
                <h1><a href="javascript:void(null)">Open the content</a></h1>
                <div id="content">
                    <p>Content 2</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

It works just fine until here. Now i want to create an condition with PHP that echo something when any  has have the class .open  but I cant figure out how to write this one. Here is what i came up with:

```
            <? if '#content'.class='open'{
                  echo include('column-right1.php'); 
                  echo include('column-right2.php'); 
                }
                else {
                  echo include('column-right3.php');  
                {
            ?>
```

If this isnt possible in PHP how would be the script on javaScript and/or Jquery for it?

Comment: Think you're getting mixed up between JavaScript and PHP somewhere in there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question but it looks like you want to do this in JS, not in PHP.

Comment: I think you're greatly misunderstanding how PHP works. How long have you spent learning PHP?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why you are trying to do this? Why do you need to know the class in PHP, instead of HTML/Javascript.

Comment: Also, its called Javascript, not java. Thats a whole other story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I would use jquery and do something like this:

1. give an id to div where you're appending ".aberto" like id="content" class="content aberto"
2. Check if the class exists
3. Load the php file you want

> ```
> if ($('#content').hasClass('aberto')) {
>    $("#some_div_id").load('column-right1.php');
>    $("#other_div_id").load('column-right2.php');
> }else{
>    $("#else_div_id").load('column-right3.php');
> }
> ```

Adapt it and try it ;)

You should start by including a file in your index.php right before closing the  tag ... something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.daterraweb.com/js/onload.js"></script>
```

Then in file onload.js you place the code mentioned above... like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 if ($('#content').hasClass('aberto')) {
       $("#some_div_id").load('column-right1.php');
       $("#other_div_id").load('column-right2.php');
    }else{
       $("#else_div_id").load('column-right3.php');
    }
}
```

1. You should be carefull with the paths for php files
2. You should have all the important divs with the id desired and match it with the jquery code.

NOTE: If you want to load the content right after you insert the .open class you should simply change to something like this:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
              $(function() {
                    $('.container h1').bind('click', function() {
                        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
                            $(this).parent().find('.content').slideUp();
                            $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
                            $("#else_div_id").load('column-right3.php');
                            return 0;
                        }
                        $(this).parent().parent().find('.content').slideUp();
                        $(this).parent().find('.content').slideDown();
                        $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                        $("#some_div_id").load('column-right1.php');
                        $("#other_div_id").load('column-right2.php');
                    })
                 });
        </script>
```

Comment: I'm not  quite sure about how to this actually. When i first saw your answer it looked good but now I'm a bit confused. 

Here is what I'm doing. www.daterraweb.com


I'm trying to open a include inside the right column of the page when one of those content boxes are open and other when they are close

So... how would I begin this JqueryCode?

Comment: well se my edited repply above. I didn't test the code but it should be something around that. If you find additional problems try using alert or console.log(someVar) or drop a word

Comment: Hey Jr.. Thank you very much. I was able to develop the idea based on what you wrote. Let me know if you ever need my expertise as well. I'm always down to help. Thanks one more time.

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand the fundemental difference between clientside and serverside scripting.

PHP runs on your server, and prepares the page before its send to the user. This is serverside, the backend of your application. Everything that happens here is on your central servers, if you'd for example tried to open a file that would be on your servers hard drive.

After the client recieves your requests your HTML/CSS/Javascript is parsed, this all is client-side. Everything here has to do with the user, nothing goes back to the server. In this environment to interact with the user, for example ask his mouse position or hide and show different elements.

So, in short, PHP cant interact with the user but is central and in one place, while javascript can and is distributed between your users.

Comment: Well.. i was hoping that PHP would do that, and that's exactly what I need. I need PHP to check if the <div id="content"> has the class .open each is added or removed by a javaScript. So, basically I need the php to ask the <div id="content"> if it has the class .open and if so do something and if not do something else. I hope this clarify a little more my question. Tnx.

Comment: Why is it important that you know this in PHP, instead of in javascript? Because its not possible, without doing a callback to the server somehow.

Comment: Im gonna post the java script I guess.. :p

Comment: oh... i actually got what you are saying... I guess AJAX will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing PHP and HTML/css. I'd recommend checking elsewhere in your code to see what the class is being set as, and doing it that way. Otherwise you'd need to use output buffering and it will get very messy for a simple HTML template.

Long story short, you're mixing two things in ways they cannot be mixed.

Comment: I don't see a problem mixing PHP and HTML or on this case (X)HTML. I just want to make the PHP CODE to very if a class exist for a certain DIV or not and if so, echo something and if not echo something else. I hope that helps to clarify my question. Tnx.

Comment: It's not physically possible to mix them in the way you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in PHP, without rendering your full HTML contents to some PHP function. Some users will definitely post some weird frameworks for that, but that's the wrong thing to do.

You have to understand, that PHP gets calculated before HTML does. So this method is fundamentally impossible. You should work other way around. You should define HTML class, based on PHP, not other-way around. What are the conditions of having the class 'alberto' in your container?

Is it like this, that your JavaScript is adding this class dynamically and then you wish to PHP act on it? That brings to another point, that PHP is not very dynamic in that way. PHP needs a reload to display the results (unless, used via AJAX.) However, if you want to change the contents of your container based on the class.. You can also use JavaScript for that and the AJAX method. Meaning, that JavaScript will load the contents from a remote PHP file and change the HTML contents of your container.

> **Some reading material for you:**
>
> 1. http://www.sitepoint.com/ajax-jquery/
> 2. http://webdosanddonts.com/fundamental-php-coding-dos-donts

**PS:** Also your if statement is incorrect. Correct would be: `if ($foo == true)`